# Setting queueSize option on SEDA

Tags: queue, apache-camel

I have a seda queue where i set queueSize option according to the [camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/seda.html)

The route i have looks like:

```
from("seda:someQueue?concurrentConsumers=10&queueSize=10")
.process(someProcessor);
```

I'm getting the following error due to the queueSize option:

org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route....bla bla bla..
There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties of the endpoint. Unknown parameters=[{queueSize=10}].....
[stacktrace continues here]

Can anyone point out what's wrong?
I'm using Java 8, Camel 2.9.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the documentation says that the option queueSize is **component** only, which mean you need to configure it on the `SedaComponent` instead. In other words you cannot configure it on the endpoint as you do in your route above.

For up to date documentation and better docs on Camel components, then browse github pages at: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-seda/src/main/docs/seda-component.adoc

Those docs are up to date and show both component vs endpoint options in different tables, so its easier to know the difference.

Comment: Can you show me an example how you can configure the option on SedaComponent using Java DSL?

Comment: Look at the unit tests in camel-core and you can find some examples how it test itself

Comment: updated documentation location: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-seda/src/main/docs/seda-component.adoc

Answer (score 3):

For those who have the same question, this is how i use the queueSize now

Initialize a new seda component,

```
SedaComponent sedaComponent = new SedaComponent();
        sedaComponent.setQueueSize(3);
        context.addComponent("sedaComponent", sedaComponent);
```

then use this component at the route like,

```
from("seda:someEndPoint?concurrentConsumers=5")
                             .to("sedaComponent:someOtherSedaEndPoint?blockWhenFull=true");
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a specific queue . it is quarkus example replace Named as bean and ApplicationScoped to Configuration for Spring boot

```
@ApplicationScoped
public  class ConnectionConf {

    @Named("NonLimitQueue")
    @Produces
    public BlockingQueue arrayDeque(){
        return new ArrayBlockingQueue(30000);
    }
}
```

camel side

```
 from("seda:queue=#NonLimitQueue")
            .convertBodyTo(String.class).log("${body}")
```

Answer (score -2):

Replace `queueSize` 
with

```
size(query param in apache document)
    from("seda:someQueue?concurrentConsumers=10&queueSize=10")
.process(someProcessor);
```

Comment: Who's class is the `size` method? your solution is basically useless without this information